# Can we use approaching to

Tags: prepositions

I am trying to explain to my student the reason why it is not possible to say "I am approaching to the beach". It doesn't sound correct to me, but I don't know how to explain why.

Comment: It is simply a fact about the verb _approach_ that it takes a direct object, not a _to_ phrase. There is no reason for this: it is just how English happens to be at present. (It might be different next century, for all we know).

Answer (score 1):

"Approach" means "move nearer to":

So you can't say it that way because it would mean:

> I am moving nearer to to the beach.

To address some things others have brought up:

> I am approaching from the beach.

What has happened here is that the destination has been omitted (probably due to it already having been established). Consider a conversation:

> What side of the restaurant will I see you from?
>
> I am approaching from the beach.

A fuller, less conversational statement would need to be:

> I am approaching the restaurant from the beach.

With regards to:

> It's a new approach to the problem.

I think of "approach" as a noun here. It is also more abstract, and refers more to a "style/way/fashion of approaching something". Also, I see "to the problem" here as expressing that the approach belongs to the problem (we're really "moving towards" a solution, not a problem), or that the problem will "experience" the approach as being new. Consider other phrases:

> A new approach to marketing.
>
> A new approach to keeping fit.

The actual destination we are "moving toward" (with the "approach") is implied, but not stated, in statements like these.

Answer (score 0):

"I am approaching" requires an object after it, e.g. "the beach". In your sentence, you provided a direction: "**to** the beach".

So it will be correct to say:

> I am approaching the beach.

Comment: This sounded okay at first, until I thought about it a bit longer. We certainly can provide a direction without an object directly afterwards (*approaching **from** the beach*). I provided a longer answer—even though I still couldn't come up with an objective rule.

Comment: What can I say, you are actually right :)

Answer (score 0):

You could say this:

> ✔ I am approaching the beach.

You could *also* say this:

> ✔ I am approaching **from** the beach.

If you want to keep *to*, you can do so be replacing the verb:

> ✔ I am ***going*** **to** the beach.

But the sentence as you have it is unidiomatic:

> ✘ I am approaching **to** the beach.

---

It is difficult for me to come up with a rule for this.

We have *go to* and *come from*—however, we can also use *go from* and *come to*. But, for some reason, it's only *approach from* that's the verbal phrase used in your particular sentence.

Yet, strangely, we can say this:

> ✔ It's a new approach to the problem.

We can even say this:

> ✔ They walked in a cautious approach to the beach.

---

You might think, then, that given all of these other ways of using the words, *I am approaching **to** the beach* would be fine. In fact, if I "turn off" the part of my mind that knows it's not normally said, it doesn't sound so bad. Especially when I've first thought of the earlier examples I gave.

Here's what [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=approaching%20to%20the%2C%20approaching%20from%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Capproaching%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capproaching%20from%20the%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Capproaching%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capproaching%20from%20the%3B%2Cc0) shows:

[image: approach from or to]

Currently, *approaching* ***from*** is found more often in writing than *approaching* ***to***, which is almost nonexistent. What's interesting is that the reverse seems to have been true at one point—until the commonality of the two terms switched roles around 1880.

In short, I can think of no grammatical (syntactical) reason why we should not use *approaching* ***to***. It's simply the case that we normally don't. For whatever reason.